# Flurry analytics on Firefox OS privileged app

Tags: javascript, html, analytics, flurry, firefox-os

I have a Firefox OS app that makes calls to cross domain pages and downloads data to display on the app, wich all works fine because I used the systemXHR permission and appended the { mozSystem: true } on every XMLHttpRequest.

Then I attached the Flurry script, made the FlurryAgent calls in the .js of the app and started recieving the info from the events on the Flurry Event Logs when I ran it on the Firefox OS Simulator. When I tried to install my app on a Firefox OS device, the Flurry session never starts and the app never loads.

I don't understand why Flurry works on the simulator and not on the device. I checked a lot of times for the internet connection on the device, wich works fine for the browser and other apps that were already installed. And my app worked fine on the device before I had attached Flurry.

Here is a sample of my code:

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.flurry.com/js/flurry.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>


</head> 


<body>
```

.js

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role="page"]', function(){    
    if ($(this).attr('id')=="splash"){
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    }
});
$(document).on('pageinit', '[data-role="page"]', function(){    
    console && console.log($(this).attr('id') + " - pageinit!!");
    if ($(this).attr('id')=="splash"){
        FlurryAgent.startSession("7ZFX9Z4CVT66KJBVP7CF"); //Here is were it crashes
        alert("Inicio sesion flurry");
        console && console.log($(this).attr('id') + "- Entro al if para el timer");
        var timer = window.setTimeout(next, 10000);
    } 
});
```

If there is anything else that you need to help me figure out what happens, let me know.
The device I'm using is a Qualcomm model, especifically Peak and has the OS version: Boot2Gecko 1.1.1.0hd-GP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a CSP issue.  Have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/CSP?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Apps%2FCSP Specifically Remote scripts are banned.

Comment: Thanks for that info!! It worked perfectly when I downloaded the .js from Flurry and saved it with the rest of the javascript files of my app. Conclusion: don't use remote scripts with Firefox OS apps!

Comment: Agreed, but with the caveat that the conclusion is only relevant to privileged apps and higher.  Hosted and packaged apps without privilege are fine.